# Automatic conversion of types for FFI calls in Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeclass, ffi

I have defined the following module to help me with FFI function export:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies, TypeSynonymInstances #-}
module ExportFFI where

import Foreign
import Foreign.C


class FFI basic ffitype | basic -> ffitype where
    toFFI :: basic -> IO ffitype
    fromFFI :: ffitype -> IO basic
    freeFFI :: ffitype -> IO ()

instance FFI String CString where
    toFFI = newCString
    fromFFI = peekCString
    freeFFI = free
```

I'm struggling with the instance for functions. Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you know about [FunPtr](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/Foreign-Ptr.html#t%3AFunPtr)?  If not then see Foreign.Ptr and its related documentation.

Comment: Yes, I know it. The idea here is to make an automatic conversion to/from FFI. For example `String -> String` would became `CString -> CString`, or something similar.

Comment: Please don't use Haskell extensions in FFI binding libraries!!! it makes it really difficult to build with other Haskell compilers that don't support those extensions used.

Comment: Sorry, but the same holds with any other code. Why make FFI special?

Comment: I already mentioned why, it makes it difficult to reuse binding libraries with other Haskell compilers, there is no need to use extensions for bindings. You end up with duplicated efforts.

I've been trying to build a binding library on jhc so I can use it on the Wii but this library uses multi-param type-classes quite similar to what you're doing and it wasn't even necessary, luckily I managed to get rid of it with a single parameter type class and type constraints in fact my changes actually made the code better than the original code while still being haskell98 compatible code.

Comment: Again, there is **nothing special about FFI** code here. If I use certain extensions I know that the code won't be portable. It's difficult to reuse **any** kind of library if it uses extensions that your compiler doesn't support.

Comment: My point is, if you release a binding library for others to use those type of libraries are more likely to be used by a lot more people, yes of course it depends but in general that is the case.

Comment: @snk_kid Perhaps jhc should improve support for haskell extensions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two things you can do with functions involving the FFI:
  1) Marshalling: this means converting a function to a type that can be exported through the FFI.  This accomplished by `FunPtr`.
  2) Exporting: this means creating a means for non-Haskell code to call into a Haskell function.

Your FFI class helps with marshalling, and first I create a few sample instances of how to marshal functions.

This is untested, but it compiles and I expect it would work.  First, let's change the class slightly:

```
class FFI basic ffitype | basic -> ffitype, ffitype -> basic where
    toFFI :: basic -> IO ffitype
    fromFFI :: ffitype -> IO basic
    freeFFI :: ffitype -> IO ()
```

This says that given the type of either "basic" or "ffitype", the other is fixed[1].  This means it's no longer possible to marshal two different values to the same type, e.g. you can no longer have both

```
instance FFI Int CInt where

instance FFI Int32 CInt where
```

The reason for this is because `freeFFI` can't be used as you've defined it; there's no way to determine which instance to select from just the ffitype.  Alternatively you could change the type  to `freeFFI :: ffitype -> basic -> IO ()`, or (better?) `freeFFI :: ffitype -> IO basic`.  Then you wouldn't need fundeps at all.

The only way to allocate a FunPtr is with a "foreign import" statement, which only works with fully instantiated types.  You also need to enable the `ForeignFunctionInterface` extension.  As a result the `toFFI` function, which should return an `IO (FunPtr x)`, can't be polymorphic over function types.  In other words, you'd need this:

```
foreign import ccall "wrapper"
  mkIntFn :: (Int32 -> Int32) -> IO (FunPtr (Int32 -> Int32))

foreign import ccall "dynamic"
  dynIntFn :: FunPtr (Int32 -> Int32) -> (Int32 -> Int32)

instance FFI (Int32 -> Int32) (FunPtr (Int32 -> Int32)) where
    toFFI = mkIntFn
    fromFFI = return . dynIntFn
    freeFFI = freeHaskellFunPtr
```

for every different function type you want to marshal.  You also need the `FlexibleInstances` extension for this instance. There are a few restrictions imposed by the FFI: every type must be a marshallable foreign type, and the function return type must be either a marshallable foreign type or an IO action which returns a marshallable foreign type.

For non-marshallable types (e.g. Strings) you need something slightly more complex.  First of all, since marshalling happens in IO you can only marshal functions that result in an IO action.
  If you want to marshal pure functions, e.g. (String -> String), you need to lift them to the form (String -> IO String).[2]  Let's define two helpers:

```
wrapFn :: (FFI a ca, FFI b cb) => (a -> IO b) -> (ca -> IO cb)
wrapFn fn = fromFFI >=> fn >=> toFFI

unwrapFn :: (FFI a ca, FFI b cb) => (ca -> IO cb) -> (a -> IO b)
unwrapFn fn a = bracket (toFFI a) freeFFI (fn >=> fromFFI)
```

These convert the types of functions to the appropriate marshalled values, e.g. `wrapStrFn :: (String -> IO String) -> (CString -> IO CString); wrapStrFn = wrapFn`.  Note that `unwrapFn` uses "Control.Exception.bracket" to ensure the resource is freed in case of exceptions.  Ignoring this you could write `unwrapFn fn = toFFI >=> fn >=> fromFFI`; see the similarity to wrapFn.

Now that we have these helpers we can start to write instances:

```
foreign import ccall "wrapper"
  mkStrFn :: (CString -> IO CString) -> IO (FunPtr (CString -> IO CString))

foreign import ccall "dynamic"
  dynStrFn :: FunPtr (CString -> IO CString) -> (CString -> IO CString)

instance FFI (String -> IO String) (FunPtr (CString -> IO CString)) where
    toFFI = mkStrFn . wrapFn
    fromFFI = return . unwrapFn . dynStrFn
    freeFFI = freeHaskellFunPtr
```

As before, it's not possible to make these functions polymorphic, which leads to my biggest reservation about this system.  It's a lot of overhead because you need to create separate wrappers and instances for each type of function.  Unless you're doing a lot of marshalling of functions, I would seriously doubt it's worth the effort.

That's how you can marshal functions, but what if you want to make them available to calling code?  This other process is **exporting** the function, and we've already developed most of what's necessary.

Exported functions must have marshallable types, just like `FunPtr`s.  We can simply re-use the `wrapFn` to do this.  To export a few functions all you need to do is wrap them with `wrapFn` and export the wrapped versions:

```
f1 :: Int -> Int
f1 = (+2)

f2 :: String -> String
f2 = reverse

f3 :: String -> IO Int
f3 = return . length

foreign export ccall f1Wrapped :: CInt -> IO CInt
f1Wrapped = wrapFn (return . f1)

foreign export ccall f2Wrapped :: CString -> IO CString
f2Wrapped = wrapFn (return . f2)

foreign export ccall f3Wrapped :: CString -> IO CInt
f3Wrapped = wrapFn f3
```

Unfortunately this setup only works for single-argument functions.  To support all functions, let's make another class:

```
class ExportFunction a b where
  exportFunction :: a -> b

instance (FFI a ca, FFI b cb) => ExportFunction (a->b) (ca -> IO cb) where
  exportFunction fn = (wrapFn (return . fn))

instance (FFI a ca, FFI b cb, FFI d cd) => ExportFunction (a->b->d) (ca->cb->IO cd) where
  exportFunction fn = \ca cb -> do
    a <- fromFFI ca
    b <- fromFFI cb
    toFFI $ fn a b
```

Now we can use `exportFunction` for functions with 1 and 2 arguments:

```
f4 :: Int -> Int -> Int
f4 = (+)

f4Wrapped :: CInt -> CInt -> IO CInt
f4Wrapped = exportFunction f4

foreign export ccall f4Wrapped :: CInt -> CInt -> IO CInt

f3Wrapped2 = :: CString -> IO CInt
f3Wrapped2 = exportFunction f3

foreign export ccall f3Wrapped2 :: CString -> IO CInt
f3Wrapped2 = exportFunction f3
```

Now you just need to write more instances of `ExportFunction` to automatically convert any function to the appropriate type for exporting.  I think this is the best you can do without either either using some type of pre-processor or unsafePerformIO.

[1] Technically, I don't think there's any need for the "basic -> ffitype" fundep, so you could remove it to enable one basic type to map to multiple ffitypes.  One reason to do so would be to map all sized ints to Integers, although the `toFFI` implementations would be lossy.

[2] A slight simplification.  You could marshal a function `String -> String` to the FFI type of `CString -> IO CString`.  But now you can't convert the `CString -> IO CString` function back to `String -> String` because of the IO in the return type.

Comment: Forgot to mention, this only applies to exporting Haskell functions.  Importing functions through the FFI would best be handled with something like c2hs or GreenCard.

Comment: My primary focus is on `foreign export`. I'm not sure how would your solution map to exporting functions. FunPtr isn't really important here because of this.

Comment: You need a FunPtr to marshal a function, which is what your FFI class does (i.e. it marshals stuff).  I've added a bit to explain how to use it to export functions, but there's still some work to do.

Comment: Reviving this an eternity later as I am trying to do something similar.... But I don't think your `ExportFunction` class will work as you have described. Your two instances appear to be overlapping, as I think a function `(a -> b -> c)` is going to match the first instance where `a :: a` and `b :: (b -> c)` resulting in a signature of `(ca -> IO (cb -> cc))` which is not the desired result.

Comment: I suspect it worked at the time.  I think it would still work if you enable OverlappingInstances (or appropriate instance-level pragmas), because the second instance is strictly more specific than the first.  OverlappingInstances isn't great, but in limited circumstances it's not horrible either.