# Integrating Haskell with .Net?

Tags: .net, haskell, interop

I was wondering if there is any good documentation out there for integrating Haskell with the outside world (specifically .NET).  I would like to be able to call Haskell functions from within my .NET code.  I saw that there was a previously posed question that showed how to pass strings back and forth, but I was wondering if there are more general references and the possibility of passing more complex type.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494478/call-a-haskell-function-in-net

Comment: I read that thread an it showed one specific example of calling a string function.  I am looking for more general documentation on how to export functions out of Haskell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call a Haskell function in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494478/call-a-haskell-function-in-net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably read the stuff in [that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494478/call-an-haskell-function-in-net) more clearly, because it does actually give links to relevant stuff. But here's a bullet-point version anyway:

- You can call unmanaged native code from .NET using [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services). See the end of the Wikipedia article for tutorials and documentation on this part.
- You can export Haskell functions through [Haskell's FFI](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/Using_the_FFI). Make sure you export the functions with the correct calling convention (stdcall, not ccall). See also GHC's [FFI documentation](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/users_guide/ffi-ghc.html).

So basically what you want to do is export your Haskell functions as if you were going to use them from C, build a DLL with the functions you want, then use P/Invoke to call the Haskell functions. And definitely re-read the accepted answer to the other question, it mentions several pitfalls you'll need to avoid.

Comment: I guess this seems to be the best resource I've found as well.  I also found this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3338940/automatic-conversion-of-types-for-ffi-calls-in-haskell

Answer (score 4):

[hs-dotnet: Pragmatic .NET interop for Haskell](http://haskell.forkio.com/dotnet/)